# z3py: assumptions from (check-sat ...) statement

Tags: z3, z3py

Is there a way to pass assumptions from (check-sat ...) statement of SMT2 formula into the solver ?

Consider the following example formula stored in ex.smt2:

```
# cat ex.smt2 
(declare-fun p () Bool)
(assert (not p))
(check-sat p)
```

Running z3 on it gives unsat, as expected. Now, I'd like to solve with assumptions (p) through z3py interface:

```
In [30]: ctx = z3.Context()
In [31]: s = z3.Solver(ctx=ctx)
In [32]: f = z3.parse_smt2_file("ex.smt2", ctx=ctx)
In [33]: s.add(f)
In [34]: s.check()
Out[34]: sat
```

Is there an API to get assumptions (i.e. (p) in this example) from the parser ? Or even better, just tell the solver to solve with the assumptions read from the input file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such API. The `parse_smt2_file` API is very simple, and only provides access to the assertions in the input file. Extending this API is in the TODO list, but nobody is currently working on that.